# How to access data in block which is passed from controller

Tags: magento2.3.3

I have a controller and I have created block using createBlock method in controller and have passed a userid to it

> $block =  $this->_pageFactory->create();
>
> $block->getLayout()
>   ->createBlock('Magecomp\Crud\Block\GetUserById','magecompcrud.edituser',['data'=>['userid'=>$userid]]);

Now how can I access this userid in blcok or blcok method

Answer (score 0):

you can use setData after createBlock

example

> $block->getLayout()->createBlock()->setData('key',value)

To retrieve data from block

> $block->getData('key');